# Fetch the API response that occurs after on click

Tags: cypress, response

I want to fetch the API response that I receive on clicking a button.
In my use-case, after click the button, the response data is loaded on the page.

I need to get the response data upon clicking the button rather than testing the loaded page.

How can I perform this using Cypress?

Comment: You can intercept the request and access the response, but why don't you want to test what the user's actually shown?!

Comment: I'm testing the what's actually shown to user as well but I also want to test what I get from the api data as well. Do you have an example of how to intercept the request and access the response?

Comment: Then read https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests

Comment: My own preference would be to perform separate API and page-related tests to keep avoid complications, see [API and Integration Tests](https://learn.cypress.io/advanced-cypress-concepts/integration-and-api-tests) and linked example application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe mentions, [you can use `cy.intercept()` to listen for the request,](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) and [then `cy.wait()` on the alias of the intercept to retrieve the data.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Waiting)

Assumptions made in the example below are called out via comments

```js
cy.intercept('/foo') // assumes request is made to something like www.my-url.com/foo
  .as('foo'); // assign the intercept an alias
cy.get('button') // find the button
  .click() // and click it
cy.wait('@foo') // wait for the request to finish
  .then((interception) => {
    // Assertions on the request here
    // Convenience variable assignment
    const { body } = interception.response
    expect(body).to.not.be.null;
  });
```